# Disable "End Message" page completely

Tags: limesurvey

Looking for a way to have the last question redirect to another site. I do not want the "end message" page to be displayed at all. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Survey settings --> Automatically load URL when survey complete.

https://manual.limesurvey.org/Survey_settings#Presentation_.26_navigation